# Error Coming in UI but response coming correct in console

Tags: reactjs, restful-authentication

Here is my code for fetching notes using ContextAPI to pass the function between components:

```js
const [notes, setNote] = useState([]);

let GETchallNotes = async () => { 
  let response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/fetchNotes`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
      "auth-token":authtoken,
    },
  });
  const json = await response.json(); 
  console.log(json);
  setNote(json);
};

return (
  <NoteContext.Provider
    value={{ notes, deleteNote, addNote, updateNote, GETchallNotes }}
  >
    {props.children}
  </NoteContext.Provider>
);
```

In my `Note` component, I am using `useEffect` to trigger the `GETchallNotes` function. However, even though the notes are properly being fetched and logged to the console, I am experiencing a UI error. Here is my `Note` component:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import NoteContext from '../context/NoteContext';
import NoteItem from './NoteItem';
import AddNote from './AddNote';

function Note() {
  const provider=useContext(NoteContext)
  const {notes, GETchallNotes}=provider;

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("Triggered")
    GETchallNotes();
  },[]);

  return (
    <>
      <AddNote></AddNote>
      <div className='row my-3'>
        <h2>Your Notes</h2>  
        {notes.map((item) => {
          return <NoteItem note={item}></NoteItem>
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Note
```

[image: You can see image here]
What could be causing this UI error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot it seems that the value that is being returned from the API you're calling is an object with a key `notes` that has the value of the list of notes that you're looking for.

The reason you're getting the error is that an object doesn't allow the function `map`.

Here is the revised code:

```
const [notes, setNote] = useState([]);

let GETchallNotes = async () => { 
  let response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/fetchNotes`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
      "auth-token":authtoken,
    },
  });
  const json = await response.json(); 
  console.log(json);
  setNote(json?.notes ?? []);
};

return (
  <NoteContext.Provider
    value={{ notes, deleteNote, addNote, updateNote, GETchallNotes }}
  >
    {props.children}
  </NoteContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: Thanks mate , it works but can you explain what did you do what does that syntax mean inside the setNote?

Comment: Of course! You got an object from the response, the syntax means that we try to get the value of the key ‘notes’, that should be a list of notes. If the key doesn’t exist, we use an empty list.